# Prototype Element.update multiple objects

Tags: constructor, prototypejs, append

I'm trying to construct a table with Prototype's New Element function. I was experiencing problems in Firefox when I was updating the thead with the complete content: all th elements plus contents. Firefox was stripping the tags and displays only the contents.

Anyways I decided to construct every single th element and then append it to the thead utilizing the `Element.update()` function. But I haven't found a way to append multiple objects with this function.

The th elements look like this:

```
var thead_amount = new Element('th', {
    'id': 'amount'
}).update('amount');
```

This works fine:

```
new Element('thead').update(thead_amount);
```

This outputs the same as above:

```
new Element('thead').update(thead_amount, thead_pdf, thead_tags, thead_date, thead_options);
```

This outputs `[object HTMLTableCellElement][object HTMLTableCellElement][object HTMLTableCellElement][object HTMLTableCellElement][object HTMLTableCellElement]`

```
new Element('thead').update(thead_amount + thead_pdf + thead_tags + thead_date + thead_options);
```

How can I append multiple objects with Prototype's `update()` function?

Thanks!

Comment: I also tried innerHTML but no changes in Firefox! The thead should be like this:
    <th id="amount">amount</th><th id="tags">tags</th><th id="date">date</th><th id="attachment">attachment</th><th id="options"></th>

but it only shows:
    <thead>amounttagsdateattachment</thead>

Very weird behaviour in Firefox. It strips the tags or does not close them..

I can't find a solution to this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

It just jumped out at me that you are adding "TH" elements to a "THEAD". This is bad! A THEAD should contain only TR's. TR's can contain TH's, but if you're using THEAD I would use TD's instead.

Remember: tbody, thead, and tfoot are subdivisions of table, and *must* contain tr elements. You should not put td or th elements directly into these, as the results are unpredictable at best.

**End Edit**

The problem here is that Element.update() has to be passed a string, HTML snippet, or a javascript object that implements toString (e.g. Element). However, Element does not support the '+' operator as you are using it, and adds together the object names as you see. You would have to explicitly call the toString method on each child as such:

```
new Element('thead').update(thead_amount.toString()
  + thead_pdf.toString() 
  + thead_tags.toString() 
  + thead_date.toString() 
  + thead_options.toString());
```

If you are using script.aculo.us in your app (a Prototype extension), you can use the Builder class to assist in easier Element construction. It provides a much more intuitive interface, especially when creating large numbers of Elements. Here is an example:

```
var table = Builder.node('table', {
  width: '100%',
  cellpadding: '2',
  cellspacing: '0',
  border: '0'
});

var tbody = Builder.node('tbody'),
    tr = Builder.node('tr', { className: 'header' }),
    td = Builder.node('td', [Builder.node('strong', 'Category')]);

tr.appendChild(td);
tbody.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(tbody);

$('divCat').appendChild(table);
```

Check out http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/builder for details.

Comment: Scriptaculous' Builder function is wonderful! Just what I was looking for, thanks a lot! Also thanks for clearing that up about thead and th, in fact I was using tr's before but a friend of me gave me a wrong suggestion on that :P Works perfect now in FF where nothing did before because of it not creating the nodes :) Thanks!