# Prototype Element.toggle on hover, disables with childElements

Tags: hover, prototypejs, children

I got the following situation:

I got a table structure like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td>text</td>
  <td><a href="#"><img src="#" /></td>
  <td><span style="display:hidden"><a href="#">e</a> <a href="#">e</a></td>
</tr>
```

What I'm doing with the following function is displaying the hidden span on hover of the table row. However it quirks whenever I hover the childElements inside the tr: the anchored image and the span itself. How can I fix this?

```
// Reveal item options on hover
$$('#financedata tr').invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function(event) {
    event.target.up().childElements()[4].childElements()[0].toggle();                   
}); 
$$('#financedata tr').invoke('observe', 'mouseout', function(event) {
    event.target.up().childElements()[4].childElements()[0].toggle();
});
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it quirks"? Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry. Whenever I hover a childElement, javascript thinks I hover out of the parent Element so it hides the span. But in fact my cursor is still in the parent Element (the tr).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$$('#financedata tr').invoke('observe', 'mouseout', function(event) {
    this.up('tbody').childElements()[4].childElements()[0].toggle();
});
```

The key is using "this". With Prototype, "this" will always be the element the event is bound to, whereas event.target (which you shouldn't use as it is not cross-browser) and event.findElement() will be the actual element that the event occurred on. The .up('tbody') is merely a personal preference, and ensures that you are selecting the parent tbody, and nothing else. Try it with or without.

Read: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe for more information and examples on how Event bubbling works.

Comment: P.S. You may need to change tbody to table depending on your DOM markup.

Comment: Also note that some browsers (Firefox) implicitly add a tbody to your DOM when you don't specify one, so watch out for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :) I will be reading more about Event bubbling and the use if this in an observer. I actually did not had to use up()  with this since as you stated, the event is bound to the <tr>.

Comment: Btw I found thead and tbody to be quite buggy in Firefox. Do you happen to know a solution to my other problem with Firefox? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111337/prototype-element-update-multiple-objects