# Prototype Hover Content and Children

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I am using:

```
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  
$$('li').invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function(event) {
    this.children[0].toggle();
});

$$('li').invoke('observe', 'mouseout', function(event) {
    document.children[0].toggle();
});
    });   

<ul>
  <li>
    <div style="display:hidden;">Hidden Div</div>
    <div>More content that isn't hidden</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To display a hidden div within an element when that element is moused over. It is partially working, however my code looks like the following:

When I rollover the li it displays the hidden div, however if I rollover the second div it hides the comment again, even though this div is in the li. Why? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159695/prototype-element-toggle-on-hover-disables-with-childelements) questions, but it doesn't seem to work either for this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use prototype or javascript for this, use css

```
li.item:hover div.entry {
 display:block
}

li.item div.entry {
 display:none
}
```

you don:t use any css classes in your example code, but I would strongly recommend you do so for this case

```
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="entry">Hidden Div</div>
    <div>More content that isn't hidden</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you're right, it won't. Which is another reason why unless you have an extremely compelling reason to do otherwise, you should cease supporting IE6. A not-insignificant proportion of web users disable javascript or do not have it available for accessibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the div that you want to perform the toggle on. Then inside the event handler use this.select() to find children with that class name.

```
 <ul>
  <li>
    <div class="hidden">Hidden Div</div>
    <div>More content that isn't hidden</div>
  </li>
</ul>

Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {  
    var lis = $$('li');

    var toggleFunc = function(event) {
        this.select('.hidden').toggle();
    }

    lis.observe('mouseover', toggleFunc);
    lis.observe('mouseout', toggleFunc);
});
```

Comment: mouseover and mouseout are not reliable enough for a toggle function. use addClassName() and removeClassName() instead. it's simply too easy to leave the item without triggering the mouseout (e.g. at the window edge).

Comment: if you are adding and removing classes won't you still have to have mouseover and mouseout triggers to know when to add and remove the classes? That's all I can tell from the documentation.

Comment: @Ryan yes, but while you might have it erroneously stay open/closed once, it won't result in toggling to the wrong state on the next valid mouseover/mouseout. e.g. it avoids this scenario: valid mouseover -> toggle to unhidden. invalid mouseout -> no change. mouse re-enters browser window and then performs a valid mouseover -> toggle to hidden. And now you have the opposite of expected behaviour. mouseover hiding, and mouseout unhiding due to the toggle state.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to use [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/protohover/) which adds "mouseEnter" and "mouseLeave" functionality for non-IE browsers.

Comment: Since 1.6.1, mouseenter is built into Prototype.